# Correspondence between terms in generic path integrals

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, hamiltonian-formalism, path-integral, coherent-states

In field theory, starting with a quantum Hamiltonian with field operator $c$, no matter its nature, one  obtains the path integral formulation with partition function $$Z=\int DcDc^* \exp{ -S^1_E[c,c^*]}\tag{1a}$$ with
$$S_E^1=\int_\tau d\tau c^*\partial_\tau c + \text{H}(c,c^*)\tag{1b},$$ the first term is the term from coherent states measure, sometimes referred to as a berry phase.

However, in usual path integral formulation of quantum field theory, I rarely see this term mentioned since theories are not derived from a Hamiltonian (and why aren't they ?), for instance for a massive free scalar field $$S_E^2=\int d^Dx \frac{1}{2}((\partial \phi)^2 + m^2 \phi^2) + V(\phi)\tag{2}.$$ A reason might be that it has been reabsorbed, from an integration by parts, but I can't say for sure. Why would field theories have different types of free parts, some with $\phi^*\partial_\tau \phi$ and others with $(\partial \phi)^2$?

I have not seen some lecture notes starting from the quantum Hamiltonian present in $S_E^1$, of a usual bosonic condensed matter system in second quantized form for example, and arriving at the usual terms of $S_E^2$. This would be interesting to have.

Ideally I would like some details of this correspondence between the usual terms one find in quantum Hamiltonian (of condensed matter systems for instance, with not so exotic interactions) and the usual terms that are in Lagrangian formulation of quantum field theories.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use Euclidean formulations? For the formulation with the $c$ field, are you following a reference? Which page?

Comment: The correct derivation of the path integral does start from a Hamiltonian. In some cases this is important, since starting from the Lagrangian can give you the incorrect path integral (as discussed in Weinberg). A freely available resource where this is discussed is Ch 6-8 of Srednicki's QFT notes, https://chaosbook.org/FieldTheory/extras/SrednickiQFT03.pdf

Comment: @Qmechanic a reference is Negele, Orland - Quantum Many-particle Systems, Eq. (2.66) p. 69. One reason is that $S_2$ could be the $\phi^4$ theory of magnetism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP's 2 Euclidean formulations are equivalent. To compare

- Firstly, rewrite the Grassmann-even complex field$$c~=~\frac{\phi+i\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$$
  into its real and imaginary parts.
- Secondly, change the term
  $$c^{\ast}\frac{dc}{dt_E}
  \quad\longrightarrow\quad
  c^{\ast}\frac{dc}{dt_E}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{dc^{\ast}c}{dt_E}
  ~=~\frac{1}{2}c^{\ast}\frac{dc}{dt_E}-\frac{1}{2}c\frac{dc^{\ast}}{dt_E}~=~-i \pi\frac{d\phi}{dt_E}$$
  with a total time derivative. This does not affect the classical EOMs (but it does change boundary conditions).
- Thirdly, for the real scalar field (2), Legendre transform the Euclidean Lagrangian formulation
  $$ {\cal L}_E~=~\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dt_E}\right)^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2 +\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi +{\cal V}(\phi)$$
  into the corresponding Euclidean Hamiltonian formulation
  $$ {\cal L}^H_E ~=~-i \pi\frac{d\phi}{dt_E} + {\cal H}, \qquad 
  {\cal H}~=~ \frac{1}{2}\pi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2 +\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi+{\cal V}(\phi). $$

Comment: Does it work with covariant derivative ? (abelian and non-abelian cases)

Comment: Well, it should. Have you checked?

Comment: Thank you, indeed it should follow from the property of a derivative that Leibniz rule holds. As a sanity check, it follows that $c^* D_o c\rightarrow c^*\frac{D_0c}{2}-c\frac{D_0c^*}{2}$, then I should redefine the canonical momenta with an extra gauge field term to obtain the result.